# Laravel Cannot use Select and With

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have 3 tables :
`reservation`
`reservation_kit`
`kit`

I use this command to get all the reservations with columns `resPickDate` and `resReturnDate`. I want to get also the kits

```
    $reservations = Reservation::with('kits:kitNo')
    ->select('resPickDate', 'resReturnDate')
    ->get();
```

Problem1: if I uncomment the select, I get something like
`{"resPickDate":"2018-10-29","resReturnDate":"2018-10-29","kits":[]}`

Problem2: If I comment the select, the `with('kits:kitNo')` doesn't get only the no, I get also the pivot
`"kits":[{"kitNo":"ACC_AUDIO-SPEAKERS_6840.01","pivot":{...}}`

How could I get only the resPickDate and resReturnDate with Kits ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its a many to many usually using this kind of binding it breaks the join because you are using a select it only looks for the specific fields, now i don't know how to do binding like this with a many to many like this but you can try:

```
Reservation::with('kits:kitNo')
->get()
->map(function ($item, $key){ 
  return [
    "resPickDate" => $item->resPickDate, 
    "resReturnDate" => $item->resReturnDate,
    "kits" => $item->pivot 
  ]; 
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. The id of the kit table is named `idKit`. I tried to replace id by idKit, but not working. I also tried with the foreign key name, same result :c

Comment: WHat is your primary eky and foreign key names?

Comment: Primary : idKit and foreign : fkKit

Comment: How does the BelongsTo or Has on Reservation look like?

Comment: Anyway should bef ine if it works without select : have you tried 
`Reservation::with('kits:idKit,kitNo')
->get(['resPickDate', 'resReturnDate', 'fkKit']);`

Comment: laravel put the `fkKit` in select, but it's a manyToMany relation so it cannot work (I get field not exist)

Comment: @mytDRAGON `"kits" => $item->pivot ` might also be `"kits" => $item->kits ` dono try both

Comment: Thank you so much! That's almost what I wanted, I just had to change `$item->kits` to `$item->kits->pluck('kitNo')` for getting only the no c: